# How to remove the validation schema if input field unmount react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form that will render the fields conditional. I use react-hook-form to validate the form

**Case 1:** If user checked checkbox, the field firstName will display and required fill value for firstName. Then user can submit a form

**Case 2:** If user not checked checkbox, form can't submit because it still subcribe to validation schema

This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/unregister-react-hook-form-j7bim6?file=/src/App.js:0-1587

I expected if user not check the checkbox, user still can submit the form without field firstName. I tried use `shouldUnregister: true` but it not remove the validation against firstName input. If i remove validation schema, everything work fine but I need to validate the form, so I can't remove validation schema

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: *Moderators are empowered (at their discretion) to issue **immediate suspensions of up to 30 days** to users who are copying and pasting GPT content onto the site, with or without prior notice or warning.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `firstName` dependent on `showFieldFirstName` inside your schema too. check below updated schema, working fine in your codesandbox.

```
...
const SignupSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().when("showFieldFirstName", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required()
  })
});
...
```